# Assigning subtables to unknown indices in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm totally new to Lua Script and I'm trying to assign an indexed value to an index in an empty table like this:

```
table = {}
table[6].id = 231
```

p.s. the above code is a simplification of a bigger script for Digital Combat Simulator using MOOSE Framework.

I got the following log message:

> ... DCS: Mission script error: ... attempt to index field '?' (a nil
>   value)

Sorry if it looks stupid but I couldn't find what is wrong with it.
Do I even need to declare the table in first place?

Thank you

Comment: Note: The only thing "declared" in Lua is local variables (as opposed to global variables). And, the only thing "defined" in Lua is a function definition that creates a function value _when it is executed_. You probably meant "construct" a table, which, similarly, creates a table value _when the table construction expression is executed_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is correct, but you are accessing a nil value: `table[6]` is currently `nil`, so your code does something like

```
nil.id = 231
```

which is obviously not possible. Define the subtable first:

```
table = {}
table[6] = {}
table[6].id = 231
```

or use the constructor for the subtable:

```
table = {}
table[6] = { id = 231 }
```

Note that table is a pre-defined library table in lua, so you should use a different name.

Comment: I want to use id as a key. Shouldn't it be:
    table[6] = { ['id'] = 231 }
Wouldn't id be interpreted as a variable?
Is there a simpler way to express ['id']?

Comment: since 'id' is a valid variable name, it is equivalent to write `id = 231` and `['id'] = 231`. See https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.9

Comment: Of course, metatables can make a hash of things anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is correct and I recommend that you take the approach presented there.

---

You can also use metatables to automatically create tables for unknown indices.

```
local create_unknown
create_unknown = {
    __index = function(t,k)
        if not rawget(t,k) then
            rawset(t,k,setmetatable({},create_unknown))
        end
        return rawget(t,k)
    end
}

tab = setmetatable({},create_unknown)

tab[6].id = 231
tab[6].what["is"].happening = 123

print(tab[6].id)
print(tab[6].what["is"].happening)
```